# How do I replace double quotes with two different characters, based on their position in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line, terminal

Say I have a file like:

```
""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.""
```

And I’d like to transform it into german quotation:

```
"„Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.“"
```

I can use sed to replace the double quotes but how do I replace the leading pair of quotes with another character than the last pair of quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/""/\n/g;s/\n\([^\n]*\)\n/"„\1“"/g' file
```

Convert the pair `""` into a unique delimiter e.g. a newline.

Then convert pairs of the unique delimiter to the required result.

N.B. If the pairs run over a line, then use the sed option `-z` to slurp the file into memory and use a different delimiter as newlines will no longer by unique.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`, matching per line:

```
perl -pe 's/""(.*?)""/"„$1“"/g'
```

To match across multiple lines:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/""(.*?)""/"„$1“"/g'
```

For in-place editing, use `perl -i` or `perl -i.bkp`

Answer (score 0):

Not using awk but using sed and pipes you can do something like.

`sed "s/^\"\"/\"„/" /tmp/file | sed "s/\"\"$/“\"/" >> new_file;`

The more fancy way to do it would be to use groups.

`sed "s/^\"\"\(.*\)\"\"$/\"„\1“\"/" /tmp/file >> new_file`

I am not accustomed to the Unicode characters you are using so you may have to tweak that.

Comment: This works for my example but I forgot, it could also occur a case in which there might be a word before and / or after the sentence wrapped in double quotes: `Another word … ""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."" and yet another word ""Even another sentence here""`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='""' '{ORS=gensub(RS,(NR%2 ? "\"„" : "“\""),1,RT)} 1' file
"„Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.“"
Another word … "„Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.“" and yet another word "„Even another sentence here“"
"„Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit.“"
```

The above will work even if your quoted text contains newlines and was run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.""
Another word … ""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit."" and yet another word ""Even another sentence here""
""Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit.""
```